# Is this proper code for linking HTML page to separate CSS files depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css

I would like to link my HTML page to separate CSS files depending on the screen size. Does this code make sense, before I proceed and create the page and its styles?

```
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media='screen and (min-width: 768px)' />
<link href="css/styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media='screen and (min-width: 992px)' />
<link href="css/styles3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media='screen and (min-width: 1200px)' />
```

Also, since I put a media query in the link, must I also put the appropriate media query in each css file? Any help here is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should google your question before asking one here.

Comment: I did, thats why I came here.

Comment: No, this is not the correct way. Create ONE CSS, and put media-queries in the CSS-file. There is no reason to have multiple CSS-files on a site for the same media-target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

And to target certain screen size use [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) within that stylesheet. For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) { /*styles*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally load stylesheets, or use media queries in the stylesheet itself.

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a stylesheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

This is possible

More of this is explained in CSS tricks

https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/